# Is it possible to use blend that comes with VS 2012 to do WPF 4?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, blend

**Visual studio 2012 ultimate** comes with **blend**. At the moment I'm using **Visual studio 2010**. But i got a copy of **Visual studio 2012 ultimate** from a friend. However, i need use only the **blend** part of it and the code i will be doing in Visual studio 2010 in framework 4.0.

What i want to know is, is it possible to use **Blend** of **Visual studio 2012** to design UI targeting **WPF4.0** (not 4.5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Blend from VS 2012 will allow you to create WPF 4 project but then the problem you would face is the project file created by Blend will not be directly compatible with VS2010. So you would be continuously be migrating and downgrading the solution between Blend for VS2012 and VS2010.